# uploading an image to sql from remote location using wix

Tags: sql, wix

We are planning to move images that are used on our report servers to the database, because currently we have to run the installer on each report server to add the image to that server.
However our problem is that the installer might be run from a remote location as well (ie. not the db server where the image would be saved in the database). In this case Openrowset won't be able to upload our image as its on our local server, while the db server is remote.

Is there a way to upload an image from another server using our installer, which has been written in wix?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a very similar issue when using BCP. In the end I created a share over the installation directory:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetDatafileSharePath"
              Property="DATAFILE_SHARE"
              Value="\\[ComputerName]\DataLocation" />

<util:User Id="EveryoneUser"
           Name="Everyone" />

<util:FileShare Id="DataShare"
                Name="DataLocation"
                Description="Share of the datafiles.">
    <util:FileSharePermission Read="yes"
                              ReadAttributes="yes"
                              ReadPermission="yes"
                              CreateChild="yes"
                              CreateFile="yes"
                              GenericAll="yes"
                              User="EveryoneUser" />
  </util:FileShare>
```

and then ran the BCP commands using the `DATAFILE_SHARE` property. The biggest problems I had was with the permissions of the share, so you might need to change some of `FileSharePermission` settings to get it to work for you.

The other option you have if there aren't too many images and they aren't likely to change is insert them to a local sql server and then use the "Generate insert scripts" feature of [SSMS Tools](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features#GIS) to create sql inserts with the image blobs as base64 strings. Unfortunately I couldn't do that as my data changes every month.